# Django timezones and Postgresql

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, django-timezone

I know this question has discussed not for the first time but I stuck with a problem and confused a little.

So I have a celery task that should send reminders in time.

In my config:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Singapore'
```

for example I have a model like:

```
class Reminder(models.Model):
    created =  models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This is a simplified model it has more fields but problem laying inside DateTime fields.

So then I open django shell and get time like:

```
timezone.now()
reminder.created
```

It shows right time in UTC like:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 22, 8, 47, 43, 370101, tzinfo=<UTC>) #tz now
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 22, 8, 47, 43, 370101, tzinfo=<UTC>) #reminder created
```

But if I run the task from console and set up prints or trying debug with ipdb I got for time above:

```
2016-12-22 09:17:19.141242+00:00 # tz now
2016-12-22 16:52:43.366542+00:00 # reminder time CONVERT UTC+8 like Singapore but it became UTC now!!!
```

So, I can't understand how it's going. And of course I can't compare datetimes correctly in this case.

**Django 1.8 and DB PostgreSQL**

Comment: Are these two outputs from the same machine? Or is one of them running across multiple servers (i.e db/prod)

Comment: all from one, weird